# Problem get data to child component using VueX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
<template>
...
<note-info></note-info>
<note-list></note-list>
...
</template>
```

I using VueX, store.js

```
export default {
    state: {
        noteDataList: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setNoteDataList: function (state, payload) {
            state.noteDataList = payload;
        },
    }
};
```

Note List Component:

```
...
created() {
   const note_list = [{id: 1, name: "Monday"},{id: 2, name: "Tuesday"}]
   this.$store.commit("setNoteDataList", note_list);
}
...
```

Note Info Component:

```
...
computed: {
   ...mapState(['noteDataList'])
},
mounted() {
   console.log(this.$store.state.noteDataList[0]);
},
...
```

Note info component can't get first object from note list

Answer (score 1):

There's race condition, the specified order of execution cannot be expected from sibling components. They are potentially instantiated in the order they appear in a template, but this isn't guaranteed and shouldn't be relied on.

The logic that is responsible for displaying child components (`setNoteDataList`, etc) can be moved to parent component, especially if it's synchronous.

Alternatively, the component that accesses `noteDataList` shouldn't expect it to be ready on instantiation and needs to treat is as reactive value via computed properties or watchers.